# ConqueTerm bash in Vim, key input delayed

Tags: bash, unix, vim, terminal

I've just found out that I can use ConqueTerm to bring up a terminal window in Vim. But I have an annoying issue regarding this.

Lets say I go into insert mode to type commands, and then want to exit insert mode, it will not work unless I press Esc key and a different key. It seems to be a set timeout or delay of some sort. Symbols and characters show up in the bottom right corner of the terminal window.

I had the same problem when editing files in vim, but added "set timeoutlen=1000 ttimeoutlen=0" to my .vimrc which sorted this out for me. But I've been looking around and I cannot seem to find anything similar for ConqueTerm. My guess is that something is to be put/edited in "~/.vim/autoload/conque_term.vim"?!

Any help would be most apprechiated!

Thanks